# Ember.js - call methods in views initialized within handlebars

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an `App.WidgetView` which is responsible for setting up and rendering a pretty expensive 3rd party ui element, lets call this ui element `widget`.
This `widget` has a `refresh()` method. I defined a `refreshWidget()` method in `App.WidgetView` which calls `widget.refresh()`.

```
App.WidgetView = Em.View.extend({
    content: null,
    widget: null,
    init: function () {
        this._super();
        //initialize widget using content
    },
    refreshWidget: function () {
        this.get('widget').refresh();
    }
});
```

I have a list of `WidgetView`s rendered on my page using an `#each` loop pulling data from `App.widgetController`

```
{{#each App.widgetController}}
    {{view App.WidgetView contentBinding="this"}}
{{/each}}
```

Now I need to have a `refreshAll()` method in `App.widgetController` and im not too shure how to do this cleanly. Right now I have a `refresher` property in `App.widgetController` which starts at `0` and gets incrimented every time `refreshAll` is called.

```
App.widgetController.reopen({
    refresher: 0,
    refreshAll: function () {
        this.incrementProperty('refresher');
    }
});
```

Then in `App.WidgetView` there is a `refresherBinding` which is bound to `App.widgetController.refresher` and an observer which calls `refreshWidget`
when `refresher` changes

```
App.WidgetView.reopenClass({        
    refresherBinding: 'App.widgetController.refresher',
    refresherChanged: function () {
        this.refreshWidget();
    }.observes('refresher')
});
```

It does work, but im wondering if there's a clearner way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you should have a parent view that is responsible for implementing `refreshAll`, which then can loop through it's childViews telling them to refresh.